# In wso2 is 5.10 self registration how to onboard user without password

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2IS 5.11 how can we onboard user without password during self registration. I tried to disable the validation in self registration page it didn't worked. Is there any way in which we can onboard user without using password.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 identity server self-registration pages do not support passwordless self-registration. However, you can implement that via a custom page. The following link will help you.

lite user registration: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/lite-user-registration/

But if you want you can do self-registration without account locking.